# More idiomatic word order on rejected migration banner

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, migration, migration-rejection

When a question is migrated from site A to site B and then closed on site B, the migration is said to be rejected. The copy of the question on A is unlocked and becomes merely closed with only the revision history showing the migration attempt. The copy on B is unlocked and a banner under the question on B shows:

> migration rejected from [A](link) <date>

I find this message confusing: it seems to be saying that the question was rejected from A. Actually it's the migration that was rejected from A. Please change the banner to

> rejected migration from [A](link) <date>